# Scanf taking incorrect input

Tags: c

This is the only block of code where scanf doesn't seem to pick up the entered values correctly.
It always works as designed the very first time it executes the code. When it asks the second time (after executing newGame once) no matter what you type it always takes the value 1 and then on the second iteration of the infinite loop it works correctly. Using pointers didn't help like I thought it would.

Edit: updated the code for new readers, this doesn't work either

```
void newGame(void){
int option;
puts("Would you like to play a new game? 1: Yes 2: Return to the main menu");

while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch(option) {
        case 1: 
            newGame(); 
            break;
        case 2: 
            return;
        default: 
            printf("Invalid input %d!\n", option); 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int *option = calloc(1,sizeof(int));` seems like overkill.  `int option;` and `scanf("%d", &option);` will do.

Comment: yeah i was trying many things

Comment: it doesn't even print the default case

Comment: You will be more likely to get an answer if you provide a runnable snippet of code.

Comment: After the first iteration `option` has been `freed` in both the `1` and `2` cases, leaving a dangling pointer and invoking *undefined behavior* on the next read operation. Don't do that. Heed the first comment and just use `int option;` and `&option`. You should also check the result of `scanf` (the return value). If it is anything other than `1` (meaning one argument successfully parsed) making operative decisions based on the value of `option` is pointless; it was successfully populated in the first place.

Comment: The recursion is suspicious, but I don't fully understand how the observed behavior manifests so as to judge how it might be related to that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Since the PO included my code into his edited questions, I will delete my solution below since it is no longer useful. Probably, you are right about the procedure, but the PO is happy with my contribution. So I am asking myself: what is more important: to follow the procedure, or to help a person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the observed misbehavior correctly, it manifests like this (for example):

1. The function emits the prompt
2. You type "1" and hit [enter]
3. The function emits the prompt
4. You type "2" and hit [enter]
5. Nothing seems to happen
6. You type "2" and hit [enter]
7. Control passes to the next statement after the initial call to `newGame()`

At least, that's an observable behavior of the function presented.  Interpreting that to describe the problem assumes that the "Nothing seems to happen" at (5) is what the question describes as "no matter what you type it always takes the value 1".  I find it hard to reconcile those, but I assume that the code presented actually manifests the problem, so I have to somehow connect the claim to the actual behavior.

That particular behavior (having to type "2" twice or more to return to the main menu) arises from the recursive implementation of the function.  It goes like this:

- Control enters the function on the initial call to it.
- The function prints the prompt.
- The function enters the `while` loop, where:

  - it scans the user's choice (and will run into trouble either then or later if the user has entered anything non-numeric);
  - the user having entered "1", the function calls itself recursively, in which new execution it

    - prints the prompt,
    - enters the `while` loop,
    - scans the user's input ("2" this time),
    - returns *from the recursive call*.
  - (back in the top-level `newGame()` execution) the function reaches the bottom of the `while` loop and loops back to scan a new input (another "2" in the example session).
  - The function returns from the top-level execution of `newGame()`.

The *simplest* way to revise the code so that the user only needs to select option "2" once would be to add a `return` statement immediately after the recursive call to `newGame()`.  The recursive call will not return until the user has chosen option "2", so there is no need to loop back for more input in that case.

But the ***best*** solution would be to structure the menu system to be non-recursive.  In real-world programs, recursion is almost never the right answer.  Even in this case, the recursive approach puts a (system dependent) limit on how many games can be played in a row before the program overflows its stack.  That might be in the hundreds or perhaps even thousands, but there doesn't need to be any limit at all.

Comment: Interesting also what you said in your last paragraph, it seems like recursion is only practical for fancy code then in programming challenges/problems

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that the input value was actually a number -- if it is not, scanf will return 0 and not read anything.  It also might return EOF if an end-of-file is reached.  So you want something like:

```
if (scanf("%d", &option) != 1) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        printf("Unexpected end of file");
        exit(0); }
    printf("Unexpected character %c in input", getchar());
    continue; }
```

in your while loop to read your number.

Comment: I ran valgrind and I'm currently patching leaks. I fear it may have something to do with this? What's happening is that when I enter any number in the console it just goes to a new line as if it completely ignored my input

Comment: The OP's claim that the function behaves as expected on the second iteration leads me to conclude that this genuine problem with their code is not responsible for the particular issue they are asking about.

Comment: The most likely cause of the OPs reported behavior is that there's some non-digit text in the input buffer when this function is called, so it just loops repeatedly calling scanf and returning 0.  But without a complete example, its tough to tell.